# searching a Jtable for a value in a textfield

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, rowfilter

I appreciate if any one could help me solve this problem.

I am trying to search my JTable(displaying data from database table) for a user entry in a JtextField.

if the field is a text the search method will search if the text contain the entry.

Once a match is found(no mater which field contain it)  I would like the table to rearrange the rows to display the row including the textField value at the beginning.

Comment: this basic issue, similair code example contains Oracle tutorial about How to use tables

Comment: _Currently I tried to search the data base by passing a query but it did not work._ What did not work? Did you debugged your code and checked what is happening when you called _find()_ method?

Comment: Following up on mKorbel's comment the working example if found in [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)